# Prove S' is a closed subset of X

Tags: general-topology

Given the metric space $(X, d)$, with $S$ as a subset of $X$, I'm trying to prove that $S'$ is a closed subset of $X$.

My thinking is to prove that the complement $X - S'$ is open by choosing some point $x$ in the complement and showing that it is an interior point. Is it sufficient for me to say that $x$ then must be either an adherent point or an isolated point, and therefore an interior point?

Additionally, I am to find an example of a subset $S$ in the real numbers such that $(S')'$ is not equal to $S$. I'm a little lost as to what this would mean, but I'm thinking it might be true for the set $S = \{ \frac 1n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I know that the set of accumulation points for this set is ${0}$, and I'm thinking its set of accumulation points would be the null set, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: what set is $S'$?

Comment: Perhaps the prime means the complement?

Comment: @Masacroso It means the derived set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)

Comment: Sorry, yes it means the derived set! I apologize for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n \in S'$ such that $x_n \to x$

We will prove that $x \in S'$

Now each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we  have that $x_n$ is a limit point of $S$

So for  $\epsilon=1$ exists $y_1 \in S$ such that $d(x_1,y_1) < 1$

For $\epsilon=2$ exists $y_2 \in S$ such that $d(x_2,y_2)<\frac{1}{2}$

Continuing this way we find $y_n \in S$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) < \frac{1}{n}$

Thus $y_n \to x $ because $$d(y_n,x) \leq d(y_n,x_n)+d(x_n,x) \to 0$$ and $y_n \in  S$  so $x$ is a limit point of $S$ thus $x \in S'$ proving that $S'$ is closed.

For a counterexample take the open interval $(0,1)$  in the usual topology of the real line.